# How to manipulate time in excel 2007 (2 weeks 1 day 8 hours 51 minutes 38 seconds to hours)?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I need to automatically convert elapsed time in the format of days, months etc. (example - 2 weeks 1 day 8 hours 51 minutes 38 seconds) in one cell to just total hours (NOT the hour value of the value - in this example it should be 368.860556 hours). I know Google can give me the value, but I need it in Excel so if I change the value it would change it elsewhere where it needs total hours.

How could I achieve this in Excel 2007?

Comment: what exactly is the format of the elapsed time?  Do you have "2 weeks 1 day 8 hours 51 minutes 38 seconds" as text in a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have "2 weeks 1 day 8 hours 51 minutes 38 seconds" as text in cell E5:

```
=MID(E5,1,FIND("week",E5)-2)*168
    +MID(E5,FIND("day",E5)-3,2)*24
    +MID(E$5,FIND("hour",E$5)-3,2)*1
    +MID(E$5,FIND("minute",E$5)-3,2)/60
    +MID(E$5,FIND("second",E$5)-3,2)/3600
```

Returns 368.8605556

This also assumes that the format always stays as you show, such that you never have, say, "2 weeks 567 days -88 hours 9999 seconds" as input.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it right away. Is there a way to make it work when some fields only have some values (second, minute, hour and day for example) and other have values up to months (smaller values always exist but bigger ones might not)

Comment: There is a way, but it gets more complicated. Why don't you post a new question, and give us a detailed specification of the input format, along with a few examples. It's no fun coming up with an answer when the question parameters are unclear and change with time!

Comment: I managed to get everything working :) Abit of IF and IFERRORS and FIND checks and its magic :)

Thank you for your answer, it helped me to do it!:)